# Code returns nothing

Tags: programming, c

The following program was made according to the book 'Head First C'. It is supposed to be able to find and return music tracks containing a search-word, but it returns nothing. Oh, and I tried to make a 'code' space - indented it by four, but forgive me if it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>  

char tracks[][80] = {
      "I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
      "Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
      "Dancing with a Dork",
      "From here to maternity",
      "The girl from Iwo Jima",
};


void find_track(char search_for[])
{

   int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for)) 
            printf("Match found.Track %i : '%s'\n", i, tracks[i])        
  }        
}

int main()
{
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for : ");
    fgets(search_for, 80, stdin); 
    find_track(search_for);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not a bad question per se, but it doesn't contain anything to do with Ubuntu - http://stackoverflow.com/ would probably be a more suitable location.

Comment: I posted it here since I saw similar questions before, sorry about that.

Comment: So go head and close the thread.

Comment: I thought development questions were not considered off-topic?

Comment: Since when are dev question off-topic for Ask Ubuntu, its OPs choice if he wants to post them here or in SO, if he is using Ubuntu then its fine to post here. What a hell is wrong with you people?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 typos that will keep this code from compiling:

1. an extra comma after `Jima` in the array;
2. a missing semicolon at the end of the `printf` statement

If you did some `printf` debugging, you would see that `strstr` is returning `NULL` everytime, so a match is never found.

```
printf("%s", strstr( tracks[i], search_for ) );
```

Why is this? The input from `stdin` is not being terminated properly. You need to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (= EOF) after typing your search word.

In fact, you need to press it twice in order to end input and flush the buffer; then it runs as intended. Try it out. Example (it's case sensitive):

`Iwo` <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! It finally worked. But the extra comma was as given in the book, twice. And I have the semicolon in the original code. But after pressing ctrl+d twice, it works.

Comment: @user206919 The question has been re-opened. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: Btw, if it compiled with the extra comma, use `gcc -Wall` to turn on (most) compiler warnings next time. Letting things like that through will cause bugs that are next to impossible to catch later.

Comment: Finally found the 'accept' button, the tick mark, but how can I mark this thread as solved? Searches tell me to find a small triangle, which I can't seem to.

Comment: @user206919 Afaik, all you need to do is accept. Solved is for the forums. Thanks.